# For every customer select all the other customers that bought the same item

Tags: mysql, sqlite

## Database description

I have a simple database composed of three tables: customer, product and custumer_product.

- **customer**: Contains the information about the customer. His ID and name
- **product**: Contains informations about the products that are available in the store. ID and name
- **custumer_product**: junction table

---

```
- customer (table)
   id integer primary key not null
   name TEXT

- custumer_product (table)
   id_product integer
   id_customer integer
   primary key(id_product, id_customer)
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_product) REFERENCES product(id)
   FOREIGN KEY (ID_customer) REFERENCES customer(ID)
 
- product (table)
   id integer primary key not null
   name TEXT
```

---

The three tables have been initialized in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/33d84/1) by using `SQLITE`. The following SQL queries are used to construct the database

```
create table if not exists customer (id integer primary key not null, name TEXT);
create table if not exists product  (id integer primary key not null, name TEXT);
create table if not exists customer_product (id_product integer, id_customer 
integer, primary key(id_product, id_customer),  FOREIGN KEY(Id_product) REFERENCES product(id), FOREIGN KEY (ID_customer) REFERENCES customer(ID));

insert into customer(id,name)  values(1,"john");
insert into customer(id,name)  values(2,"Paul");
insert into customer(id,name)  values(3,"Jenny");
insert into customer(id,name)  values(4,"Fred");
insert into customer(id,name)  values(5,"Lea");

insert into product(id,name)  values(1,"Mouse");
insert into product(id,name)  values(2,"screen");
insert into product(id,name)  values(3,"pc");
insert into product(id,name)  values(4,"CD");
insert into product(id,name)  values(5,"Game");

insert into customer_product values(1,1);
insert into customer_product values(1,2);
insert into customer_product values(1,3);

insert into customer_product values(2,1);
insert into customer_product values(2,2);
insert into customer_product values(2,3);

insert into customer_product values(3,4);
insert into customer_product values(4,5);
insert into customer_product values(5,5);
```

---

## Problem

For every customer I want to select all the other customers that bought **at least** one similar product.

- John and Paul bought at least 1 similar product
- No customer bought a similar product as jenny yet
- Fred and lea bought a similar product

---

## output

```
"John" "Paul"
"Jenny"
"Fred" "Lea"
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a self-join and possibly an aggregation.  For instance, the following gets all customers that have purchased a similar product as another, ordered by the number of similar products:

```
select cp.id_customer, cp2.id_customer, count(*)
from customer_product cp join
     customer_product cp2
     on cp.id_product = cp2.id_product
group by cp.id_customer, cp2.id_customer
order by cp.id_customer, count(*) desc;
```

You can bring in additional information such as customer names by doing additional joins.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not entirely sure I understand the conditions, there are three basic steps to this problem, which you can combine into one query (or not).

1. Get the products that the customer bought
2. Get the IDs of the customers that bought the same products
3. Get the customer details based on those IDs

So for 1, you do a simple select:

```
SELECT id_product FROM customer_product WHERE id_customer = 1
```

For 2, you can use the `IN` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE id_product IN
    (SELECT id_product FROM customer_product WHERE id_customer = 1);
```

For 3 use a combination of `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the relevant details from the `customer` table.

Answer (score 0):

first find the list of product bought by at least 2 customers, second find the name of the custumers using the join table and third select the customer's name once. here is the query:

```
select  distinct c.name from(select c.name, p.name,cp.id_customer, cp.id_product from customer_product cp join customer c on c.id=cp.id_customer join product p on p.id=cp.id_customer where cp.id_product in(select id_product, total from(select id_product,count(*) as total from customer_product group by id_product)p where total>=2)p1)p2)
```